# I have the standard event model working, how do I add a dropdown to select additional data in the Javascript/Ajax area?

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, fullcalendar

The events in the FullCalendar are just using fields: name, start and end as in the HTML:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
       var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
           header: {
               left: 'prev,next today',
               center: 'title',
               right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
           },
           events: '/list_events',
           selectable: true,
           selectHelper: true,
           editable: true,
           eventLimit: true,
           businessHours: true,
           select: function (start, end) {
               let title = prompt("Enter Event Title");
               if (title) {
                   var start = prompt("enter start", $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
                   var end = prompt("enter end", $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
                   $.ajax({
                       type: "GET",
                       url: '/add_event',
                       data: {'title': title, 'start': start, 'end': end},
                       dataType: "json",
                       success: function (data) {
                           calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                           alert("Added Successfully");
                       },
                       error: function (data) {
                           alert('There is a problem!!!');
                       }
                   });
               }
           },
```

I would like the function to collect additional data such as status, venue and instructor, where status is a selection, and venue and instructor are DB lookups from Django event model

My Event model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Event Name', max_length=120)
    status = models.CharField(choices=EventStatus, default=EventStatus.PENDING, max_length=25)
    start = models.DateTimeField('start', default="2024-01-01 00:00:00")
    end = models.DateTimeField('end', default="2024-01-01 00:00:00")
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    instructor = models.ForeignKey(Consultant, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    # 'name', 'start', 'end', 'venue', 'contact', 'instructor'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I see there are many code snippets and examples online, but I cant see an example for this.
I am guessing I need a function to supply a var entry in this function after var start... and var end...